# How to get xerces-c to write namespaces with minimum size overhead?

Tags: xml, xerces-c

I write an xml file with xerces-c 3.2.1 which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes" ?>
<Test xmlns="my_namespace" 
      xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="my_namespace myschema.xsd">
        <Elem />
</Test>
```

with my own default namespace and the *xml* and *xsi* namespaces declared.

In my namespace, I have an attribute called **dim** which needs a namespace declaration, otherwise it would get mixed up with pre-existing **xml**:dim.

When I set this attribute with 
`elem->setAttributeNS("my_namespace", "myprefix:dim", data);`
then my xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes" ?>
<Test xmlns="my_namespace" 
      xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="my_namespace myschema.xsd">
         <Elem xmlns:myprefix="my_namespace" myprefix:dim="..."/>
</Test>
```

with the **namespace declaration at each and every element that uses *dim* attribute** I write, which is bad, because for filesize reasons, I would like to have xerces-c writing files like

(**the golden one**)

```
<Test xmlns="my_namespace" 
      xmlns:myprefix="my_namespace" 
      xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="my_namespace myschema.xsd">
         <Elem myprefix:dim="..."/>
</Test>
```

with the namespace prefix declaration just at the root node. But if I add such an entry to the root node using `root->setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:myprefix", "my_namespace");`

then xerces-c produces xml files like

```
    <Test xmlns="my_namespace" 
      xmlns:myprefix="my_namespace" 
      xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="my_namespace myschema.xsd">
         <myprefix:Elem1 ../>
         <myprefix:Elem2 ../>
         <Elem myprefix:dim="..."/>
</Test>
```

prefixing **all** other elements **myprefix:elem1**, **myprefix:elem2**, except the one with my *dim*, which is a pain in the neck...

How can I force xerces-c to my will to write a minimum amount of namespace declarations and prefixes like in **the golden one** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the trick to get **the golden one** is:

to **add the prefix to the element name** (or attribute name) e.g. *L"my_prefix:Elem"* (additionally to the namespace)

```
DOMElement * e4 = doc->createElementNS(defaultNS, (const XMLCh*)L"my_prefix:Elem");
root->appendChild(e4);
```

This saves the space in the **resulting XML** file, but requires **more space** in the code producing the XML :( and requires even more code as the prefix should not be hardcoded..